# how to access nested array in meteors

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this meteor collection. I able to get the questions to show on the page but I have no idea how to display the array 'ansChoices' separately so that I could add a radio button to each items in the array.

//my table in mongodb

> pollQuestion { "question" : "Is it fun?", "ansChoices" : [ "Yes", "No"
>   ], "_id" : "4rfqgkbZWPRjqkgAR" }

//poll.js

```
  Template.pollQn.view = function(){
    return pollQuestion.find({});
  };
```

//poll.html

```
<template name="pollQn">
    {{#each view}}
        <div class="text-inverse"><b>{{question}}</b></div>
        {{#each ansChoices}}
        <div class="text-inverse">//what should i put here to display 
        individual item in the ansChoices array</div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}} </template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your context is a string you should use the context itself: `{{this}}`